# How can I connect R Studio to my MS SQL Server database running in a virtual machine? (Parallels for MacOS Apple Silicon)

Tags: r, sql-server, macos, parallels

**This is my setup:**

- MacBook Pro 14" M1 Pro
- R Studio native on MacOS Apple Silicon.
- Parallels version 18 running the ARM version of Windows 11 with SQL Server 2014
- The above being maintained and worked on through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018

I want to connect my R Studio instance running on the host (MacOS) to my database that's running on my virtual machine.

This is my code in R Studio using Tidyverse + ODBC

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = "WINDOWSPARALLELS\\LOCALSERVERPLS", 
  Database = "CustomerSalesDW"
)
```

I get error message:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver
> Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found

If I run the same code in R Studio installed on the same virtual machine that the Microsoft SQL Server is running on, it does work. That's obvious however.

However, seeing that R Studio is painfully slow on the virtual machine, I'd rather "remotely" connect my native instance of R Studio on MacOS to the database that is running in the virtual machine.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but in Windows, you can open up an odbc control panel and see what drivers are available and test their connection.  Recommend you test the odbc connection first through your Mac OS before trying to run the R code.

Comment: `Driver = "SQL Server"` refers to the SQL Server Native Client driver (which is an old and deprecated driver) that is only available on Windows. Have you tried to use Homebrew to [install ODBC Driver 17 or 18 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos) and reference that instead? Note: Because you're using an M1 (ARM64) processor you'll need version 17.7 or later.

Comment: Aside... SQL Server 2014 on ARM? Have you installed an old 32 bit version to do that? The 64 bit version shouldn't even install, let alone start. It won't perform well and it won't give you access to any language features available on more modern releases (such as external scripts in Python and R, etc.). Have you considered using [azure-sql-edge](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) in a Docker container instead?

Comment: It's for school and they require the use of microsoft sql server management studio. Yes it's the 32 bit version, as you said the other wouldn't even install. Up until now everything we were required to do worked fine. We don't have Python but for R Studio we normally used datasheets but now we also need to be able to connect to databases that we create in SSMS.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I do have that installed yes through homebrew. However, in my virtual machine when I go to the ODBC control panel and try to add a server running ODBC I get error 193, which is weird because I do have both 32/64 bit versions installed on my vm windows.

Comment: If you're using R Studio in macOS then you also need ODBC Driver x for SQL Server installed in macOS, as per Microsoft's Homebrew recipe linked above. If you're also running things inside the VM that require the ODBC driver (SQL Server itself doesn't need it) then you'll need to install a Windows version of it inside the VM as well.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have both version 17 and 18 installed on both my mac and the VM